# Best way to store data temporarily from a windows service

Tags: .net, isolatedstorage

We are writing a long running windows service application that monitors currently logged in user's activity and writes log file (temporarily) to the file system in response to a certain event. (There is no database to write to)

Is isolated storage a good place to write it?

Will the service have access to the user's isolated storage?

Any other suggestions for this.

Thanks in advance.

Fike

Comment: The service has access to the user's isolated storage if you give it access. Are you asking for the best way to store data, or the best *place* to store data?

Answer (score 0):

A standard way is to create an event log section for your application and write to the Event log

Comment: Thx Jim, I was looking for a best 'place' to store data. As in 'best practice' If a service that is always running can write data to currently logged in user's isolated storage, that works for me. And no, we can't use the event log for this. Data we are writing needs to be hidden.